# How to use useCallback in order to fix useless render in map function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a new in **React** hooks, and I've got one question. For example, we have the following code:

```
// module with optimized React component to avoid useless renders

const Button = ({ onClick, ... }) = > {

}

export default class React.memo(Button);

// module with list

const List = ({ items }) => {
  const onSelect = item => {
    // ... do some actions with item
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {items.map(item => <Button onClick={() => onSelect(item)} />)}
    </div>
  )
}
```

As you can see, in the code above **Button** component loses all optimizations because **onClick** property will have a new link every render. How could I fix it so that **Button** works correcly with **React.memo** optimization?

Comment: FWIW, this is super basic and there are many blog posts doing this exact thing.

Comment: Give me any link please if this is so simple :)

Comment: Literally the first link when I searched "useCallback react" - https://dmitripavlutin.com/dont-overuse-react-usecallback

Answer (score 2):

This is premature optimization. Unless you find that a component is rendering many times unnecessarily and causing performance issues you should do nothing. Both useMemo and use callback have overhead so you shouldn't use them until you need to.

Comment: It's correct, but it's example for learning in order to find a way to fix my question when problem will appear really :)

Answer (score 0):

@malcoauri, I think this is it. I didn't test it, but I think it will work :)

```
// module with optimized React component to avoid useless renders

const Button = ({ onClick, ... }) = > {

}

export default class React.memo(Button);

// module with a list

const List = ({ items }) => {

 const onSelect = (item) => useCallback(() => onSelect(item), []);

  return (
    <div>
      {items.map(item => <Button onClick={onSelect.bind(null, item)} />)}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: it won't work, sorry. How onClickEvent will know which item should use?

Comment: @malcoauri Sorry, I fix it. Now it can get the item.

Comment: It doesn't work bro again. onClick must get named function, no anonymous function

Comment: @malcoauri Is that an error, or Eslint warning?

Can you try to bind onSelect function like: `onSelect.bind(null, item)` instead of `()=> onSelect(item)`?

Comment: It code doesn't fix trouble from question dude. If Button onClick property get anonymous function then Button React.memo optimizations will be broken.